# Calling another function from another class within the same main class in Android

Tags: android, methods, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I have a main Class i.e

```
Class A extends BroadcastReceiver   {

ClassB hello = new ClassB



Public void onReceive(){

// Value obtained from Method in Class B

String Message = hello.2ndFunction()

                       }


Class B extends Activity{

public String 2ndFunction(){

// 2ndFunction Lines......

                           }

                        }

                                   }
```

This is my scenario. But i get the error

```
    06-20 09:17:02.584: E/AndroidRuntime(1076): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-20 09:17:02.584: E/AndroidRuntime(1076): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.example.timesheetcalculator.ReceiveSMS: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-20 09:17:02.584: E/AndroidRuntime(1076):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2383)
06-20 09:17:02.584: E/AndroidRuntime(1076):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-20 09:17:02.584: E/AndroidRuntime(1076):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1310)
06-20 09:17:02.584: E/AndroidRuntime(1076):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-20 09:17:02.584: E/AndroidRuntime(1076):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-20 09:17:02.584: E/AndroidRuntime(1076):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-20 09:17:02.584: E/AndroidRuntime(1076):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-20 09:17:02.584: E/AndroidRuntime(1076):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-20 09:17:02.584: E/AndroidRuntime(1076):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-20 09:17:02.584: E/AndroidRuntime(1076):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-20 09:17:02.584: E/AndroidRuntime(1076):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-20 09:17:02.584: E/AndroidRuntime(1076): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-20 09:17:02.584: E/AndroidRuntime(1076):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getContentResolver(ContextWrapper.java:99)
06-20 09:17:02.584: E/AndroidRuntime(1076):     at com.example.timesheetcalculator.ReceiveSMS$CallLogsExtracter.CallLogs(ReceiveSMS.java:75)
06-20 09:17:02.584: E/AndroidRuntime(1076):     at com.example.timesheetcalculator.ReceiveSMS.onReceive(ReceiveSMS.java:47)
06-20 09:17:02.584: E/AndroidRuntime(1076):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2376)
```

What could be the problem ?

Comment: First of all your error log excerpt is too short, show the full error message with stacktrace, second, creating an activity object yourself is generally a bad idea

Comment: try like this  "ClassB hello = ClassB.getInstance(this);"

Comment: Maybe try defining he method as: `@Override public abstract void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent)` ?

Comment: @g00dy Except for the "abstract" this is right

Comment: if the line "ClassB hello = new ClassB" is meant to create a new activity instance, I don't see things going too well. You don't create activities, Android does that on your behalf when you ask it to start one. I generally create event listeners as anonymous inner classes inside the activity than needs to handle the broadcast event.

Comment: the error is in CallLogs method of your ReceiveSMS.java on 75th line, post the code.

Answer (score 0):

Error is in the function I think, related to content resolver.